Autowire RefreshScoped bean in ServletContextListener contextDestroyed, error: Error creating bean
I am building a web application that is meant to be running in Tomcat, and I need to make sure this webapp has a graceful shutdown during restart or redeploy, so I've invoked some beans' shutdown method in contextDestroy listener, and on the other hand, those beans need to be recreated with a configuration change and it also has a reference to a ConfigurationProperties bean.
Below is a simple code example:
@Component
public class OnApplicationClose implements ServletContextListener {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("newBean")
    private UserBean user;

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //assume it's bean shutdown
        user.getTest();
        ServletContextListener.super.contextDestroyed(sce);
    }
}

@RefreshScope
@Configuration("conn")
public class SomeBean{

    @Value("${spring.someValue}")
    private String someValue;

    @Autowired
    private StaticProperties staticProperties;

    @RefreshScope
    @Bean(value = "newBean")
    public UserBean createNewBean() {
        UserBean ub = new UserBean();
        ub.setTest(staticProperties.getTest());
        return ub;
    }

}

@Component(value = "staticProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf")
@PropertySource("classpath:/config/static.properties")
@Data
public class StaticProperties {

    private String test;

    
}


conf.test=test

@Component
@Data
public class UserBean {

    private String test;

}

When I close this webapp, it throws an exception:
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.UserBean]: 
Factory method 'createNewBean' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.conn' defined in file 
[/home/to/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.35/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/demo/SomeBean.class]: Initialization of bean failed;
 nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'staticProperties': 
 Could not bind properties to 'StaticProperties' : prefix=conf, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; 
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@9585a18 has been closed already

Now i have very little clue, but i think it's something related to @RefreshScope, because without this annotation everything works fine.
I think any bean with @RefreshScope will actually have two instances in context, one is a proxy instance and the other is the truely one with a scopedTarget prefix.
So it seems when spring trying to create an instance of SomeBean, it founds the context was closed, but why? this suppose to be called before context destroy,are they in different context?
